# Deck of Cards Stats Probability Question

Tags: probability, combinatorics, bayes-theorem

Randomly select two cards in sequence from a full deck of 52  cards, what i s the probability that the first one is a King given that  the second one is a King. If someone can please help me with this question.

Comment: Please mention what you have tried.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE, please update your question with your thoughts about the problem and we will be happy to guide you with hints. For example, how do you in general find $\mathbb{P}[A|B]$ for events $A,B$?\

Answer (score 3):

What are the odds that the second card drawn is a king? We pick the second card first, and there is a $\frac{1}{13}$ chance that it is a king. Any card will do for the first card. So the total probability is $1.$

What is the probability that **both** cards are kings? This probability is simply $\frac{1}{13} \times \frac{1}{17} = \frac{1}{221}.$

The conditional probability (that both cards are kings given the second is a king) then is $\frac{\frac{1}{221}}{\frac{1}{13}} = \boxed{\frac{1}{17}}.$

Comment: do you mind explaining what the difference between the probability you listed above (1/221) and the conditional probability (1/17) is?

Answer (score 2):

You might as well pick them in the other order and ask the chance the second is a King given that the first is a King.  Given that the first is a King, you are drawing from a $51$ card deck which has ????

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I misunderstood the question, corrected now.

The probability of drawing a king after you have already drawn one king is $\frac{3}{51}=\frac{1}{17}$, since there are only 3 kings and 51 cards left.

Comment: But we are given that the first is a King, so we don't count that probability.

Comment: As I read the question, what's really happening (if you imagine the situation) is that OP's question is about drawing two cards when they are both kings. Since one king is as good as any other, which one comes first doesn't matter.

Comment: This gives $P(\text{first card is K} \cap \text{second card is K})$, not $P(\text{first card is K} | \text{second card is K})$.

Answer (score 0):

By Bayes Theorem, we just need to compute the total probability the second card is a king, and then compute the fraction of that total that comes from the first card also being a king.

The total probability the second card is a king is  4/52 * 3/51 + 48/52 * 4/51.  The first summand is prob(first = king) * prob(second = king | first = king).  The second summand is prob(first card != king) * prob(second = king | first != king).

So the answer is (after noting we can eliminate common denominators in all these fractions) 4 * 3 / (4*3 + (48*4) = 3/51.

Not coincidentally, this is the same as the probability of the second card being king given that the first is king, due to the symmetry of the two situations.  When you select two cards in order from the deck, each pair that arises has a mirror image pair.  So the corresponding numbers we are concerned with are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You have one king in a known position, leaving 51 other places in the deck for the remaining 3 kings.   Given that, what is the probability that one of those three kings is in a specific place?

That is: the favoured space is ways to select 2 places from 50 (and 1 from 1).  The total space is ways to select 3 places from 51.

Divide and calculate.